# Async Page Asp.net webforms threads

Tags: asp.net, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous, webforms

I would like to solve a specific question I got, so this question is more likelly a discussion.

Basiclly, there is an asp.net project with a WebForm1.aspx, with a button on it. As soon as the clien press the button a thread is launch, and inmediatlly then, there is a Response.Redirect like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BL.Class1 cd = new BL.Class1();
    cd.Run(); // or cd.AsyncRun();
    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx",true);
}
```

Of course evrything should be nonstatic. Bussiness Logic class looks somthing like this:

```
 public class Class1
 {
    public int Signal = 0;
    // non blocking Run... the webserver continues with this process running backwards
    public void RunAsync()
    {
        Signal = 0;
        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000); // simulate heavy task!
        }
        ).Start();
        Signal = 1;
    }

    // blocking Run...
    public void Run()
    {
        Signal = 0;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000); // simulate heavy task!
        Signal = 1;
    }
}
```

With this in mind, here is the discussion:
 - In WebForm2.aspx I would like to pool either from the client (javascript/ajax/nonstatic webservice) or the server to the client (registerscript with scriptmanager), in order to have the "Signal" variable set to "True" after the heavy process.. and tell the user (via a div with red background to green color) or something else.
- If so, how would be the best method if I do not want to use SignalR or Node.js or WebApi or WebSockets jet?
- Do you have any document, book where to explain such situation in an MVC project approach?

All communitty, really thanked on helping within this issue.

br,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple meta refresh would do the trick, or a JavaScript that reloads the page on a set interval - no need for anything fancy if you don't want to.

Simply render the page (server-side) either with a red or a green div depending on the completion status of the heavy job.